# Oneconf eating up memory while in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ram, oneconf

When I look at the dependencies in Synaptic, it shows Ubuntu desktop, and software center as being dependent on `oneconf`, and I do not wish to remove these. However whenever I get to a page which has likability to social media sites (like facebook, google +, pintrest, etc.) my `oneconf` ends up jumping up to anywhere from 100 MiB usage to 700 MiB usage.

I only have 2 gig of ram, so this really hits hard on my performance. If I stop/end/kill the process it comes back again, which I expect, but it works temporarily.

Can I remove this without breaking Ubuntu? If not is there any workaround someone can think of?

[image: SysMon]

[image: HTop]